# android Camera2 take frames and convert to bitmap

Tags: kotlin, camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to convert a frame format to bitmap but always receiving null. Can someone help me with this issue?

I am using camera2 in kotlin

```
private val imageListener = ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener { reader ->
        val image = reader?.acquireLatestImage()  

        try {
            val imageBytes = image?.planes?.first()?.buffer?.toByteArray()
            val imageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
            Log.d(TAG, imageBase64)}
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        image?.close()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change it to base46, but the base64 doesn't decode. When I try to decode it online using a PNG or JPG, I always get an image with a 400x400 transparent color.

Comment: what is the ImageFormat of the received Image, if YUV you have to read all the three planes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the capture request was configured to encode the output to a JPEG?

If so you'll want to read the bytes to a byte array and then convert the jpeg to a Bitmap.

```
val buffer = image?.?planes[0]?.buffer ?: return
val jpegData = ByteArray(buffer.remaining()).apply { buffer.get(this) }
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegData, 0, jpegData.size)
```

Have you considered CameraX? It'll simplify capturing images and will manage a lot of quirks. https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo

Here's a quick overview of something you could try:

```
class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...

    val cameraController = LifecycleCameraController(this)
    cameraController.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner)

    // Attach the CameraController to PreviewView
    val previewView = findViewById(R.id.preview_view)
    previewView.setController(cameraController)

    // Take a picture
    cameraController.takePicture(
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback {
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                val jpegData = ByteArray(buffer.remaining()).apply { buffer.get(this) }
                val bitmap BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegData, 0, jpegData.size)
                // show bitmap
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: $exception")
            }
    })  
}
```